# Scale page to 1.0 using meta tags

Tags: javascript, html, scale

I use this two functions to set and reset scale values when I instigate a JS app from an HTML page.

```
function setMeta(){
        alert("meta set");
        oldcontent=$('meta[name=viewport]').attr('content') //store the current value
        $('meta[name=viewport]').attr('content', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, user-scalable=0');
}

function resetMeta(){
        alert("meta reset");
        $('meta[name=viewport]').attr('content', oldcontent);

}
```

The code works fine except if the HTML page is scaled to a larger value it doesn't get set to 1.0 as in setMeta method. Other values like `user-scalable` work fine. 
Example: In the HTML page we are alowed to scale but in the app we are not.

This doesnt work either: `document.body.style.zoom="100%";` 
why isn't the reseting of scale to 1.0 working?

Comment: Sory if I'm being too ignorant, but isn't these what you're needing?: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />`

Comment: Yes but it need to change dynamically with JS.

Comment: Oh right, sory. I'm actually a designer that more or less understands how to apply JS, not how to build it! Sory then. Luck!

Comment: It could be that there's no way to do this dynamically. I would consider an alternate solution (like serving different versions from the server)

Comment: Are you forcing a `resize` event on the window after changing the values?

Comment: `oldcontent` is definitely accessible outside of both functions?

Comment: Just an observation: my answer might not be the one you want to hear, hence not the correct one. But it does point out a flaw in your code, which might be giving the unexpected result you're getting. By defining `oldcontent` as a dynamic "value container" and changing that value when running `setMeta()` will mean that when you run `resetMeta()` you'll get the last value it was changed to - since it will request `.attr('content')` again. JavaScript is not capable of remember old dynamic values, only of returning current dynamic values. That's why you'll need two variables to get it to work.

Comment: Thought I would mention that I've tried using the browser's `localstorage` as well. Resetting fails the same way. As long as you keep calling `jQuery('meta[name=viewport]').attr('content')` whatever you try will continue to fail, because after you set the viewport's content value to something else, `oldcontent` will return the newly set content. I hope you got that by now...

Answer (score 1):

This approach is unfortunately never going to work, because the variable that stores the content attribute of the viewport meta tag (in this case `defaultContent`) is always going to fetch the current value. The only way to make this work is to define `defaultContent` explicitly, as I have done with `customContent`.

#### Firstly, let's see why the initial approach doesn't work:

Try this code on your `console` while visiting [Smashing Magazine](http://www.smashingmagazine.com):

```
defaultContent = jQuery('meta[name=viewport]').attr('content'); // store the current value in a global variable
console.log(defaultContent);

function setV(){
    // override the global variable value with a scoped variable
    var customContent = 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, user-scalable=0';
    jQuery('meta[name=viewport]').attr('content', customContent);
    console.log('Set viewport content to: ' + customContent);
}
function resetV(){
    jQuery('meta[name=viewport]').attr('content', defaultContent);
    console.log('Reset viewport content to: ' + defaultContent);
}
```

Make sure you test `setV();` or `resetV();` directly on the console, by typing them and clicking `Run` again. As you can see, it won't work because `defaultContent` is set to fetch a dynamic value, that gets changed by the `setV()` function.

#### To make it work

As I already mentioned, if you want it to work on your site, you could define a new variable with the `defaultContent` value (*default content attribute of the viewport meta tag*), so you have it properly stored from the start - like so:

```
defaultContent = 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0';
customContent = 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, user-scalable=0';

function setV(){
    jQuery('meta[name=viewport]').attr('content', customContent);
    console.log('Set viewport content to: ' + customContent);
}
function resetV(){
    jQuery('meta[name=viewport]').attr('content', defaultContent);
    console.log('Reset viewport content to: ' + defaultContent);
}
```

Not that I changed `$` to `jQuery` to avoid conflict at Smashing Magazine.

Comment: Finally all corrections are made. The first part shows why the initial approach doesn't work, the second shows what it takes to get it to work.

Comment: Yup. What I know for sure is that calling `oldcontent` dynamically (or its equivalent `defaultContent` in my example) will always return its last acquired value. So you'll have to find another way to store the original content attribute of `viewport` meta tag's value *or* know it beforehand. `JavaScript` by itself cannot store the previous default data, at least not in the way you meant to store it.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to note, when resetting the viewport tag, you must remember to **overwrite** the previous viewport attributes you set. For example, if you wish to set your viewport tag to

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

In your `resetMeta()` function, you need to set the values back to something like this

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=920, initial-scale=5.0, maximum-scale=5.0, user-scalable=yes" />
```

And not something like this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=5.0" />
```

Remembering not to miss out any widths or scales.

An edited version of your example: http://hosting.ambc.hostei.com/html/test.html

Comment: As you can see from my function I remember the old content and then set it back. That is not the problem here!